# (Failed to build scrypt-0.5.0. The failure occurred during the configure step.)

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node, blockchain

Getting erro rwhile doing "cable build all".
OS
Your OS:
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release: 22.04

Cable version :
cabal-install version 3.6.2.0
compiled using version 3.6.2.0 of the Cabal library

ghc version:
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.7

Additional context
I tried these few steps also

1)cabal clean
2)cable build all
3)sudo apt-get install libsodium-dev
4)sudo apt install libscrypt-dev

Problem Report
Installing regex-pcre-builtin-0.95.2.3.8.44 (lib)
Completed regex-pcre-builtin-0.95.2.3.8.44 (lib)
Installing Cabal-syntax-3.10.1.0 (lib)
Completed Cabal-syntax-3.10.1.0 (lib)

Failed to build scrypt-0.5.0. The failure occurred during the configure step.
Build log (
/home/ubuntu/.cabal/logs/ghc-8.10.7/scrypt-0.5.0-9dc7f5056f17df13813f95e91bb667ceed7dc3e60a8b91da16ab03a3c4c8a06b.log
):
Configuring library for scrypt-0.5.0..
cabal-3.6.2.0: Missing dependency on a foreign library:

Missing (or bad) header file: crypto_scrypt.h
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
cabal: Failed to build scrypt-0.5.0 (which is required by test:unit from
cardano-wallet-2023.7.18, exe:mock-token-metadata-server from
cardano-wallet-2023.7.18 and others). See the build log above for details.

Comment: You keep asking this same question all over the internet. Have you actually gone back and seen if there were any responses? This question really belongs on GH in the `cardano-wallet` repo. You are far more likely to get an answer there than you are here.

Comment: Thank you for your reply...